# My script is executing one time, can't figure out the reason

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

Created a grappling script that broke when adding IDs to the players.

I assign an ID whenever the game starts to each player, for local co-op reasons. It helps me assign a controller to the player. P1 is KBM, P2 and 3 are controllers.

Problem is, This code executes once and never again, Don't know why.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Grappling : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("References")]
    private PlayerMovement pm;
    public Transform gunTip;
    public LayerMask whatIsGrappleable;
    public LineRenderer lr;

    [Header("Grappling")]
    public float maxGrappleDistance;
    public float grappleDelayTime;
    public float overshootYAxis;

    private Vector3 grapplePoint;

    [Header("Cooldown")]
    public float grapplingCd;
    private float grapplingCdTimer;

    private bool grappling;

    [Header("Different Players")]
    public int playerID;

    private void Awake()
    {
        // Determine the player number based on the tag of the GameObject
        if (gameObject.CompareTag("Player1"))
        {
            playerID = 1;
        }
        else if (gameObject.CompareTag("Player2"))
        {
            playerID = 2;
        }
        else if (gameObject.CompareTag("Player3"))
        {
            playerID = 3;
        }
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        pm = GetComponent<PlayerMovement>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        Grapple();
    }

    private void LateUpdate()
    {
         if (grappling)
            lr.SetPosition(0, gunTip.position);
    }

    private void Grapple()
    {
         
        if (playerID == 1)
        {
            if (Input.GetButton("Fire1") )
            {
                StartGrapple();
                Debug.Log("Grappled!");
            }
            return 
        } 

        else if (playerID == 2)
        {
            if (Input.GetButton("Fire2") )
            {
                StartGrapple();
                Debug.Log("Grappled!");
            }
        }

        else if (playerID == 3)
        {
            if (Input.GetButton("Fire3") )
            {
                StartGrapple();
                Debug.Log("Grappled!");
            }
        }
    }

    private void StartGrapple()
    {
        if (grapplingCdTimer > 0) return;

        grappling = true;


        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.up + transform.right, out hit, maxGrappleDistance, whatIsGrappleable))
        {
            grapplePoint = hit.point;

            Invoke(nameof(ExecuteGrapple), grappleDelayTime);
        }
        else
        {
            grapplePoint = (transform.position + (transform.up + transform.right) * maxGrappleDistance);

            Invoke(nameof(StopGrapple), grappleDelayTime);
        }

        lr.enabled = true;
        lr.SetPosition(1, grapplePoint);
    }

    private void ExecuteGrapple()
    {

        Vector3 lowestPoint = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y - 1f, transform.position.z);

        float grapplePointRelativeYPos = grapplePoint.y - lowestPoint.y;
        float highestPointOnArc = grapplePointRelativeYPos + overshootYAxis;

        if (grapplePointRelativeYPos < 0) highestPointOnArc = overshootYAxis;

        pm.JumpToPosition(grapplePoint, highestPointOnArc);

        Invoke(nameof(StopGrapple), 1f);
    }

    public void StopGrapple()
    {

        grappling = false;

        grapplingCdTimer = grapplingCd;

        lr.enabled = false;

    }

    public bool IsGrappling()
    {
        return grappling;
    }

    public Vector3 GetGrapplePoint()
    {
        return grapplePoint;
    }
}
```

Comment: I suspect you are only calling the code once.  What is calling the code?

Comment: Awake only runs once, when the component is first initialized.  Are you intending to use one instance for all players?

Comment: The code is beijg accessed from my master "PlayerMovement" script but everything in that script is working as intended, only this Grapple broke. It's being triggered by my using "Fire1~3" assigned in the Input Manager

Answer (score 0):

Could be the something with the cooldown. Also in your return statement for StartGrapple(), you should also to check and see if grappling is true or if the cooldown > 0 before returning. Adds another layer to check for.

Why is there a return statement in Grapple when checking playerID == 1? It is missing a semicolon and seems unnecessary with what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: the return was leftover from a debug test, that was my bad. The code doesn't usually have it.

Answer (score 0):

I see you setting the cooldown timer but I don't see any timer actually being run.

I suspect all you are missing is:

```
void Update()
{
    grapplingCdTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
}
```

Without this your cooldown will only ever be zero when it's initialized which will allow you to only run the grappling code once.

Maybe check if your cooldown is supposed to be running here as well so that you don't run any unnecessary code, like so:

```
void Update()
{
    if (grapplingCdTimer > 0)
    {
        grapplingCdTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
        return; // Rather use 'else' if you don't want to return here.
    }

    // Run the code you currently have in Update() here.
}
```

Then you can take out the `if (grapplingCdTimer > 0) return;` at the start of `Grapple();`

Comment: Thank you so much! This fixed it, I must've deleted it at some point while debugging and forgot about it. You're the best!

Comment: Hey! I'm glad I could help. Just a tip going forward, if you ever come across issues like this, remember our good friend `Debug.Log()`. Use this to output variable values to the console. If you just used `Debug.Log($"{grapplingCdTimer}")` then you would have seen that your cooldown wasn't running.

Also, I would appreciate if you could officially accept this answer and maybe give me an upvote please? I'm new here and need that sweet, sweet rep.